# Adding custom taxonomy term facets

Tags: php, wordpress, facet, algolia, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy term called `locations` that I'd like to add facets to on re-index. The data is index as expected, along with the Searchable Attributes. However, what I'm using to do so does not seem to work;

```
function algolia_locations_faceting( array $settings ) {

    $settings['attributesForFaceting'] = array_merge($settings['attributesForFaceting'], [
        'parent',
        'type',
        'taxonomy',
    ]);

    return $settings;
}

\add_filter( 'algolia_terms_locations_index_settings', 'algolia_locations_faceting', 10, 2 );
```

I have a similar method for faceting Searchable Posts using the `algolia_searchable_posts_index_settings` filter and that works as expected, so I'm unsure why one works and the other doesnt.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you take a look inside of the Algolia dashboard and verify that the attributes "parent/type/taxonomy" are available in the records, and then check if on the "display" tab you correctly have the same attributes in the configuration for the attributes for faceting.

Comment: @rayrutjes They're all available in both the records and 'Attributes for Faceting' part of the display tab - I've had to set them manually to test our Algolia implementation on the site. Thanks.